# C# WinForms: FUSLOGVW.exe

Tags: windows, sdk

I have a problem with an application. I am testing it in a virtual machine, windows 7, and I have installed FUSLOGVW.exe via Windows SDK package. Virtual machine does not have any other software installed. When I execute FUSLOGVW.exe and click on settings button, the dialog window that appears, show all the options disabled and I cannot set the log directory when I want to put the logs. Is something missed?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to run this with admin rights.